# Calculating hash integer from a string in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm trying to calculate a hash from a string for best-effort ordering and partioning purposes in Athena. There is no String to hashCode() similar in Athena, so as a best effort, I try to get the 2nd character and calculate its codepoint and get the modulus. (As I said, best effort, maybe a nice effort)

Consider the query:

```
SELECT
    doc_id,
    substring(doc_id, 2, 1),
    typeof(split(substring(doc_id, 2, 1)))
FROM events LIMIT 100
```

The 3rd row returns a `varchar` but the codepoint function expects a `varchar(1)` and casting it does not work as `cast(substring(doc_id, 2, 1) as varchar(1))`.

```
FUNCTION_NOT_FOUND: line 6:5: Unexpected parameters (varchar) for function codepoint. Expected: codepoint(varchar(1))
```

How can I accomplish this task without modifiying the data source? I'm open to ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute a hash code with the [`xxhash64`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/binary.html?highlight=xxhash64#xxhash64) function. It takes a `varbinary` as input, so first cast the string to that type. Since the function also returns a 64-bit `varbinary` value, you can convert it to a `bigint` via the [`from_big_endian_64`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/binary.html?#from_big_endian_64) function

```
WITH t(x) AS (VALUES 'hello')
SELECT from_big_endian_64(xxhash64(cast(x AS varbinary)))
FROM t
```

output:

```
        _col0
---------------------
 2794345569481354659
(1 row)
```